# Monitor pipeline exit codes

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script which spawns a *gigantic* shell pipeline as a background process, and then spawns various other processes that communicate with it through named pipes. (Sounds complicated? Well, *it is!*) It looks something like this:

```
generate_stuff | tee >(process1) >(process2) | process3 | save_stuff &
```

The script works just fine, however... it doesn't handle errors properly. There are various error conditions which can cause one or more of the commands in the pipeline to fail. Currently the script blindly reports that everything went fine, when in fact only *some* of the commands completed successfullly.

Is there some way I can check whether *all* commands ended with exit code zero? Hopefully without making this giant script any more complex than it already is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for `set -e` and `set -o pipefail`.

From Bash manual:

```
pipefail     If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by default.
```

Answer (score 3):

You an use `$PIPESTATUS` : "Array variable holding exit status(es) of last executed foreground pipe." See more details [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

```
$ echo ok | tee | grep ko | cat
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 0 1 0
```

For a background pipe, you can try

```
$ ( echo ok | tee | grep ko | cat ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} ) &
[1] 16660
0 0 1 0
[1]+  Done                    ( echo ok | tee | grep ko | cat; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )
```

Comment: That works for the last _forground_ pipe... does it work for a _background_ pipe such as the one I'm using?

Comment: Sorry missed that part. See my updated answer. Not sure though that it would be suitable for your problem.

Comment: Hmm, looks promising! I could probably redirect `echo` to a file or a named pipe or something...

Comment: .. or maybe to a pty directly ` ... echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} > /dev/pts/1`